# Populate QTableView form JSON Array

Tags: json, qt, qtableview

I'm working on a web service client where I can get an array of JSON objects and I want to populate a QTableView with them. The JSON keys should be the column headers and values ​​should be each row data.

Example of JSON Array:

> [{"id":"1","name":"Robotina","type":"droid","year":"1970"},{"id":"2","name":"Astro Boy","type":"droid","year":"2015"},{"id":"3","name":"Terminator","type":"droid","year":"2020"},{"id":"4","name":"Bender","type":"droid","year":"3000"},{"id":"5","name":"C-3PO","type":"droid","year":"1978"},{"id":"6","name":"R2D2","type":"droid","year":"1977"},{"id":"7","name":"Mazinger Z","type":"droid","year":"1987"},{"id":"8","name":"Robocop","type":"droid","year":"1987"},{"id":"9","name":"WALL-E","type":"mechanical","year":"2200"},{"id":"10","name":"EVE","type":"mechanical","year":"2200"}]

Comment: I had a hard time to identify what your question is. And also i did not succeed :-(

Comment: So... How I can populate a QTableView (QT) with data from JSON??...

Comment: You have to write code to do it, or find some third party code that does it...as there is no make-a-UI-table-from-JSON.  You might find [QTableWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) more user friendly, as it has a default data model and you can just add rows and columns of data with API functions.  See the [JSON support in Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/json.html) for helpers to read your file.

Comment: I expected to use a structure like QSqlQueryModel but is useless, instead I will use QTableWidget as you pour Suggest and iterating data in JSON object

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem as my Json query came back as an array of hashes.

I put together a QJsonTableModel here: https://github.com/poulh/qjsontablemodel

```
QJsonTableModel::Header header;
header.push_back( QJsonTableModel::Heading( { {"title","Title"},    {"index","title"} }) );
header.push_back( QJsonTableModel::Heading( { {"title","Season"},   {"index","season"} }) );
header.push_back( QJsonTableModel::Heading( { {"title","Episode"},  {"index","episode"} }) );
header.push_back( QJsonTableModel::Heading( { {"title","Air Date"}, {"index","air_date"} }) );

episodes = new QJsonTableModel( header, this );
ui->episodeTableView->setModel( episodes );

QString json = "[{\"series\":\"Black Sails\",\"season\":1,\"episode\":1,\"title\":\"I.\",\"air_date\":\"2014-01-25\"},{\"series\":\"Black Sails\",\"season\":1,\"episode\":2,\"title\":\"II.\",\"air_date\":\"2014-02-01\"}]";
QJsonDocument jsonDocument = QJsonDocument::fromJson( json );
episodes->setJson( jsonDocument );
```

You can then retrieve the Json object for that row via the QModelIndex. It will give you the entire row's Json object regardless of which cell you clicked.

```
void TVTime::on_episodesTableView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QJsonObject object = episodes->getJsonObject( index );
    qDebug() << object["title"];
}
```

Let me know if it works.